# meaning of "in cases of this kind"

Tags: meaning

Considering the example

> **In cases of this kind** the State is bound to protect the rights of all who are within its dominion,

which is the exact meaning of "in cases of this kind"

1) in all cases of this kind

2) in some cases of this kind

?

I choose the first one, but have some doubt.

Comment: What is your doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent further qualification, the meaning is "all cases of this kind".

> Mushrooms of this kind are poisonous.
>
> Snakes of this species are venomous.